# Outlook Configurations with Web API

Tags: api, webservices, outlook, configuration

I'm searching a way to access (with the help of the Salesforce Web API) the data found under `Administration Setup > Desktop Administration > Outlook Configurations`.

That is, all configurations that I defined as well as the field mapping (Outlook <> Salesforce)...

Is this possible? I didn't find anything in the documentation (it should be possible since it is used by the Salesforce for Outlook Desktop application).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Confirming Kevin P.'s answer somewhat more concretely: Outlook Configurations, were they to be available, would be accessed through the Metadata API. While Outlook Configurations are missing from [this list](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm) of unsupported Metadata Types, other Metadata Types that use the same object prefix (Offline Briefcase Configurations, Mobile Users & Devices) are on that list, and there's nothing in the [Metadata API Settings section](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_settings.htm) about Outlook Configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The Unsupported Metadata types (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) have been updated and it includes Outlook Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

@Bidou I don't know what information is exposed, and I don't have any orgs using SF4Outlook. If you can give me some idea of what kind of information is exposed there, I can help you identify where else in the api's that information might be available.

Comment: Basically, you can create profiles which are then assigned to users. Each profile has many options, one of them beeing to allow the mapping between Outlook fields and Salesforce (custom) objects fields. With the help of Fiddler, I saw that Salesforce is querying the REST API for their "Salesforce for Outlook" App. But I didn't found anything in the documentation...

Comment: @Bidou you're probably seeing it query a private api resource not documented, or meant to be used by anyone outside of salesforce. As the old maps used to say: "There be dragons". I suspect strongly that there is no support for api interaction with SF4Outlook configuration profiles.